# Extract year from datetime64[ns] in Pandas but not int type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given a date columns with type `datetime64[ns]`, I want to extract `year` from them:

```
array(['1998-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', 'NaT', 
       '2009-10-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2009-10-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2009-10-03T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I have used `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.year`, it generates date with `.0` as follows:

```
0       1998.0
1       1998.0
2       2003.0
3       2000.0
4       2005.0

1877    2002.0
1878    2012.0
1879    2012.0
1880    2013.0
1881    2015.0
Name: date, Length: 1882, dtype: float64
```

So I try to use `fillna(0)` then convert to `int` and replace `0` with `NaN`, but it gives same result as above.

`pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.year.fillna(0).astype(int).replace(0, np.nan)`

Does somebody could help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Use `astype('Int64')` which is nullable integer type in later pandas.

Comment: Tested. This also works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No recommend but match the expected output , since the column now have mix datatype

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.year.astype(object)
0    1998
1     NaN
2    2009
3    2009
4    2009
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great it works. Could you explain `.dt.year` doesn't give the correct answer? As I know, in most case, it works no need to convert type.

Comment: @ahbon pandas always try to downcast the whole column to one datatype, NaN is consider float , that is why int become float ~

Answer (score 1):

Alternative do `datetimeindex.year` to convert the datetime to numeric year. Not a one liner though. Please see
Data

```
data=['1998-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', 'NaT' 
       '2009-10-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2009-10-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2009-10-03T00:00:00.000000000']
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':data})
```

Coerce and set as index

```
  df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Extract numeric year

```
df['date']=df.index.year
df.dropna().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```